# Exists a continuos function $\mathfrak{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathfrak{R}^3$ that is fully defined on $\mathfrak{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis

Given that

$$f: D \rightarrow \mathfrak{R}^3$$

and $D= {(x,y,z) \in \mathfrak{R}^3 | x \neq 0 \quad OR\quad y \neq 0 }$

with

$$f(x,y,z)=\left(x*z,y^2+z^2,\frac{y*z}{x^2+y^2}\right)^T$$

Does a continous function $\stackrel{~}{f}:\mathfrak{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathfrak{R}^3$ exist that is fully definied on $\mathfrak{R}^3$ AND that is equal to $f(x,y,z)$ for all
$x,y,z \in D$

My idea for constructing the function was to first separate f into components and then use L'Hospital to get the limits for the single variables and then use these to contruct the function but i am unsure as to whether that is

a) "legal"

b) the proper way to do this

Comment: Fix $x=0$ and $z=1$, and try to take a limit as $y\to0$.

Comment: Your proposed method is certainly a "legal" one, and would be a reasonable thing to try.  Unfortunately, as mr_e_man's comment shows, it won't actually work, because .... .